# Why are people still using iron lungs, rather than something like a tracheostomy?

Tags: breathing

As per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_lung#Modern_development_and_usage)

> In 2021, the National Public Radio programs Radio Diaries and All Things Considered gave a report on Martha Lillard, one of the last two Americans depending on the daily use of an iron lung, which she had been using since 1953. In her audio interview, she reported that she was having problems obtaining replacement parts to keep her machine working properly.

From what I understand, the iron lung is used for people who have trouble breathing. Normally the diaphragm moves down, increasing the space in the lung. That causes the pressure the lower and air from the outside to enter. Then the diaphragm moves up, decreasing the space in the lung. That causes the pressure to raise and the air in the lunges exit. If your diaphragm is not strong enough, then the iron lung can help by raising and lowering the pressure around the lungs, causing a similar effect.

However, there are many issues with an iron lung. You aren't mobile and nowadays there is an issue finding parts.

It seems to me that a tracheostomy would be a simple solution. That could be attached to a breathing machine that will push air in and such air out.

Why are people still in iron lungs (and were for a while since tracheostomies became standard)?

Comment: I had basically the inverse question: https://associationofanaesthetists-publications.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/anae.15350?fbclid=IwAR1UHClP1IcLsP3yvruqem7GEGrVf4l-s19WTHV43XrEwGtcpQq2705qPsA

Comment: Interesting article. I like how the modern iron lung looks. I guess for short periods of time (or for people who may at some point recover), that could be useful.